# Form gets sent to wrong page?

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile

I have small issue with a form that seems to be sent to the wrong page in JQuery mobile.

I have a form that is located in this directory:

```
etc/res/form.html
```

When i call this from my index page all works fine and dandy:

```
$.mobile.changePage('etc/res/form.html', {transition: 'slidedown', role: 'dialog'});
```

i have also a page in:

```
etc/rus/settings.html
```

from there i call the above form page:

```
$.mobile.changePage('../../etc/res/form.html', {transition: 'slidedown', role: 'dialog'});
```

the form shows up in a dialog window just like it should. But as soon as i try to submit the form the form get´s loaded again...this time without any information sent to it and without the "dialog style". How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to solve this we are going to need more of the code that you are using to load the form and possibly the outer portions of the form itself.  The problem likely lies at some point were you load the form.  I am willing to take a guess that you are using a relative url in the form itself and that it is likely the culprit here, but again without more code it is very difficult to tell.  Please expand the question here with more code or use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).  Thank you.